# Centroid of the region bounded by y = f(x) and x = f(y) curve

Tags: integration, centroid

How do i find the centroid of the region if $x = f(y)$ is involved ?
For example : find the centroid of the region bounded by $y = x^2$ and $x = y^2$

And how do i find it if there is curve intersection that is below x axis ?
For example : find the centroid of the region bounded by $y = x^3$ and $x = y^2-1$

The formula I found in the book was
$$x = \frac 1{\mathcal{A}}\int_a^b x[f(x)-g(x)] \,dx$$
$$y = \frac 1{\mathcal{A}}\int_a^b \frac 12 (f(x)^2-g(x)^2) \,dx$$

$\mathcal{A}$ is the area of the region bounded by the curve.

Answer (score 3):

In this case you can first try to sketch the region, as shown below.

[image]

From the sketch we learn that it suffice to consider the first quadrant where $ x, y \geq 0 $.
Thus the equation $ x = y^2 $ can be converted to $ y = \sqrt{x} $.
Put $ f(x) = \sqrt{x} $, $ g(x) = x^2 $, $ a = 0 $, $ b = 1 $, and using the formulae you have given yield
$$ A = \int_0^1 \sqrt{x} - x^2 \operatorname{d}\!x = \left. \frac23 x^{3/2} - \frac13 x^3 \right|^1_0 = \frac13,  $$
$$ x = \frac1A \int_0^1 x(\sqrt{x} - x^2) \operatorname{d}\!x = 3 \left[ \frac25 x^{5/2} - \frac14 x^4 \right]_0^1 = 0.45, $$
and
$$ y = \frac1A \int_0^1 \frac12 [(\sqrt{x})^2 - (x^2)^2]\operatorname{d}\!x = \frac32 \left[ \frac12 x^2 - \frac15 x^5  \right]_0^1 = 0.45. $$

Comment: ah thank you ! okay it might be outside my example but i wonder how to find the centroid if the curve intersection is below x axis ? my bad i didn't ask this earlier , but anyway this answered my homework thanks

Comment: Yeah. I'll fix that in my answer, thanks.

Comment: i've edited my question and give an example that involve the problem of curve intersection below x axis , i'm sorry i didn't ask it earlier

Comment: I will not detail too much since it is better that you try to work out. But the basic principle is to observe which region you need to perform integration and then simplify the relevant expressions, as demonstrated in the above.

Comment: yes i understand that but i don't know how to do it if one of the curve intersection is below x axis , what should i do with the x = f(y) ??